# How to make Looping and Calculate formula from another workbook without open file

Tags: vba, excel

I want to ask how to do this from vba code

Workbook 1 contain cell A, cell B, cell C
Workbook 2 contain Cell D
each cell contains number value
Cell D = (Cell A - Cell B) * Cell C

i want to calculate and just return value to cell D in workbook 2, Here my code snippet

```
  Dim path As String
    Dim workbookName As String
    Dim worksheetName As String
    Dim cella As String, cellb As String, cellc As String
    Dim returnedValue1 As String, returnedValue2 As String, returnedValue3 As String
    Dim Hasil1 As Long

    path = "D:\"
    workbookName = "Workbook1"
    worksheetName = "Daily"

    cella = "F7"
    cellb = "E7"
    cellc = "D7"
    returnedValue1 = "'" & path & "[" & workbookName & "]" & _
          worksheetName & "'!" & Range(cella).Address(True, True, -4150)
    returnedValue2 = "'" & path & "[" & workbookName & "]" & _
          worksheetName & "'!" & Range(cellb).Address(True, True, -4150)
    returnedValue3 = "'" & path & "[" & workbookName & "]" & _
          worksheetName & "'!" & Range(cellc).Address(True, True, -4150)

    Worksheets("Workbook2").Cells(D).Value = CLng(ExecuteExcel4Macro(returnedValue1) - ExecuteExcel4Macro(returnedValue2)) * ExecuteExcel4Macro(returnedValue3)
```

as far my code was good, but how to do it in one column, i have many cell beside just cell A. I want to calculate like this
Column D = (Column A - Column B ) * COlumn C

thanks for your answer..

Comment: Have you tried with a loop? You can use a for loop to repeat some code as many times as you want.  See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Is Calculation set to automatic in your Excel Application? What I mean is when you saved Workbook 2 before closing were all formulas updated in Col D? If yes then you can directly pick up values from Col D

Comment: Another faster method(I think) is to use `ACE.OLEDB` to read the 3 columns into a temp sheet and then perform the calculation. Yes, `ACE.OLEDB` will open the other excel file but it doesn't open it like Excel does.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that (while row in column A is not empty, it populates your expression in column D):

```
Sub mmacro()
    Dim path As String
    Dim workbookName As String
    Dim worksheetName As String
    Dim cella As String, cellb As String, cellc As String, celld As String

    Dim returnedValue1 As String, returnedValue2 As String, returnedValue3 As String
    Dim Hasil1 As Long
    Dim rownum As Integer
    Dim A As Integer, B As Integer, C As Integer, D As Integer

    path = "D:\tmp\"
    workbookName = "Book2"
    worksheetName = "Sheet1"

    cella = "F"
    cellb = "E"
    cellc = "D"

    celld = "A"

    rownum = 3'Data starts in row 3 in my example

    Do
        returnedValue1 = "'" & path & "[" & workbookName & "]" & _
              worksheetName & "'!" & Range(cella & rownum).Address(True, True, -4150)
        returnedValue2 = "'" & path & "[" & workbookName & "]" & _
              worksheetName & "'!" & Range(cellb & rownum).Address(True, True, -4150)
        returnedValue3 = "'" & path & "[" & workbookName & "]" & _
              worksheetName & "'!" & Range(cellc & rownum).Address(True, True, -4150)

        A = CInt(ExecuteExcel4Macro(returnedValue1))
        B = CInt(ExecuteExcel4Macro(returnedValue2))
        C = CInt(ExecuteExcel4Macro(returnedValue3))
        D = (A - B) * C

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(celld & rownum).Value = D
        rownum = rownum + 1
    Loop While Not D = 0
End Sub
```

This is just example. It is needed to be refined

Comment: Thanks for your  reply...
but i need in some rows not all of one column. suggest only row 3 until 10, how to do that, your loop just for all of one column.. please...

Comment: @BudiSetiawan you can replace `Loop While Not D = 0` with `Loop While rownum <= 10`

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment here is a faster method which **DOESN'T** use looping. Use ACE.OLEDB to read the 3 columns into a temp sheet and then perform the calculation. Yes, ACE.OLEDB will open the other excel file but it doesn't open it like Excel does.

**Note**: The below code uses Early binding and please set a reference to the ActiveX Object Data XX.XX Library.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim sConn As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim mySQL As String, sPath As String
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim wsILRow As Long, i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant Excel File
    sPath = "C:\MyFile.xlsx"

    '~~> Change connection string if the above is not xlsx
    sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
               "Data Source=" & sPath & ";" & _
               "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"

    '~~> Assuming that workbook 2 has sheet1 from where you want data
    mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A:C]"

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open mySQL, sConn, adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified

    '~~> Create a temp sheeet to get the data from closed file
    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    '~~> Dump the data in the temp sheet
    wsI.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    '~~> Close the recordset
    rs.Close
    sConn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set sConn = Nothing

    '~~> Get last row from temp sheet
    wsILRow = wsI.Range("A" & wsI.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> This is where you want the output
    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With wsO
        '~~> Insert values in one go
        .Range("D1:D" & wsILRow).Formula = "=(" & wsI.Name & "!A1 - " & _
                                           wsI.Name & "!B1) * " & _
                                           wsI.Name & "!C1"
        '~~> Change formulas to values
        .Range("D1:D" & wsILRow).Value = .Range("D1:D" & wsILRow).Value
    End With

    '~~> Delete tmep sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsI.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... but i dont undestand with SQL

Comment: It's not that difficult if you give it a try :)